# JavaFX AudioClip: any way to play more sounds at the same time?

Tags: java, javafx, audioclip

First question on Stack Overflow, please have mercy if I don't know all the conventions yet. :)

I'm playing sounds with JavaFX AudioClip, and I'm running out of sound channels. I'm doing my best to fiddle with the priority, stop, and isPlaying methods, but if there's lots of action on screen, sounds get interrupted a lot.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html) says: "The number of simultaneous sounds that can be played is implementation- and possibly system-dependent."

What does "implementation-dependent" mean? Is there anything I can do to increase the number of available sound channels?